# angular 2 pipe for credit cards

Tags: angular

I want to create a pipe, that adds a space every 4 digits of a credit/debit card number.

this one hides all but the last 4 digits.

```
export class CreditCardMaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(plainCreditCard: string): string {
    const visibleDigits = 4;
    let maskedSection = plainCreditCard.slice(0, -visibleDigits);
    let visibleSection = plainCreditCard.slice(-visibleDigits);
    return maskedSection.replace(/./g, '*') + visibleSection;
  }
}
```

something like this but to add the spaces.

Comment: Test it please `[...str].map((chr, idx) => (idx + 1) % 4 ? chr : chr + ' ').join('');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
export class CreditCardMaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(plainCreditCard: string): string {
    return plainCreditCard.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
  }
}
```

```js
const plainCreditCard = '1234567891234567';
function transform(cardNumber) {
    return cardNumber.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
}
console.log(transform(plainCreditCard));
```

Comment: the digits are not transformed after applying the pipe.

Comment: I added a runnable snippet to prove that my code in fact works as expected, I am not sure why it is not working for you

Comment: get this error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at CreditCardPipe.webpackJsonp.516.CreditCardPipe.transform

Comment: import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'creditCard'
    })
    export class CreditCardPipe implements PipeTransform {
       transform(cardNumber: string): string {
        return cardNumber.replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
     }
   }

this is the pipe file

Comment: Are you invoking the pipe like this `"cardNumber | creditCard:cardNumber"`,  in another word, are you passing the number to the pipe in your template?

Comment: I have this
[ngModel]="cardNumber | creditCard:cardNumber"

its on an input, not sure if that matters.

Comment: The error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` means that the number you passing to the transform function of the pipe class has value `undefined`, since you are passing something to your pipe, so make sure that this is not the case

Comment: I only get the error when I use the pipe, I am able to fill the credit card form otherwise.

Comment: It is because `cardNumber` propertg in your form class starts out unitialized, it is only filled in when you start typing into the text box, and you apply the pipe to it, angular processes your form when you starts that's why you are getting that error on startup. Also, pipes are used to format data for representation, I don't know why you need to do that on `ngModel` binding

Comment: I'm using it in a stripe payment form, but I find it hard to look at 16 digits together to verify its the correct card number.

Comment: Just initialize the property `cardNumber` to an empty string, it should get rid of the error since uninitialized variables are assigned `undefined` by default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144293/discussion-between-mel-pacheco-and-dummy).

Comment: thanks man, that helped, I dont get errors anymore, however the digits come out like this '4242 4242 424'
4242....... 4242...424 the periods are the spaces, the autocorrect changed in the chat

Comment: So the function above will insert a space whenever it encounters 4 digits, it **should not** insert more than one space

Comment: yea its weird, if I paste it its fine, it's only when I type them one at a time

Comment: the same issue, it's so weird, only when I type in. it works after the first 4 digits, but then it adds a space for every new digit.

Comment: this one clears the field after 3 digits. thank you for taking the time to help me by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
numberList = 1234223432344234;
outStrint="";
for (var i = 0;i+4<= numberList.toString().length; i+=4) {
    outStrint=outStrint+numberList.toString().slice(i, i + 4)+" "
}
console.log(outStrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
return [...plainCreditCard].map((chr, idx) => (idx + 1) % 4 ? chr : chr + ' ').join('').trim();
```

Simple snippet:

```js
const plainCreditCard = '1234567890123456';

const test = [...plainCreditCard].map((chr, idx) => (idx + 1) % 4 ? chr : chr + ' ').join('').trim();
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to late but it can be helpful for other who search for similar problems
**NGX Mask** is  really helpful in  transforming card, phone numbers etc...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask

```
<span>{{creditCard | mask: '0000 0000 0000 0000'}}</span>
```